# Copying Files in a Folder To Individual Folders

Tags: files, directory, rename

This might sound like something quite odd but for my HTPC, I need to rearrange how my files are stored such that each of the individual files in a folder needs to be moved to a subdirectory of its own (with the same name as the file).

I.E. - Currently the directory is:

```
directory/
- a.file
- b.file
- c.file
```

and I want to change it to:

```
directory/
- a/
-- a.file
- b/
-- b.file
- c/
-- c.file
```

I don't think this is terribly tricky but it's just odd and I haven't found anybody doing it before: I think it can be done with find and exec but I'm a bit of a battler and can't quite get it.

Thank you very much in advance (or even just for taking the time to read this).

Comment: Always the same extension?

Comment: No, but all the files in the folder I want this done too. Also, there's only 3 or so file extensions so if you know a way of doing it for the same extension, I could just run the command thrice, changing the extension each time: it's not a huge concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a shell script which gets the files as parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filepath; do
  parentpath="${filepath%/*}"
  if [ "$parentpath" != "$filepath" ]; then # $file contains a /
    file="${filepath#"$parentpath"/}"
  else
    file="$filepath"
    parentpath=""
  fi
  filename="${file%.*}"
  if [ -z "$parentpath" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$filename" && mv "$file" "$filename"
  else
    mkdir -p "${parentpath}/$filename" &&
      mv "$filepath" "${parentpath}/$filename"
  fi
done
```

You can call this script as `./script *.ext1 *.ext2 *.ext3` for not too huge numbers of files or as `find ... -exec ./script {} +` for huge numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly: exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

Dir="/tmp/directory/"

for f in "$Dir"/*;
do
    SubDir="${f%.*}"
    mkdir -- "$SubDir"
    mv -- "${f}" "$SubDir/"
done
```